# Node.jar : release status and expected roadmap

Tags: nashorn

Ive been looking arround stackoverflow for informations about nashorn lately and node.jar too. But i noticed there is still nothing covered about node.jar.

Does anyone have a document or extended resource about current project status as well as its roadmap ?

p.s: i suggest someone creates a node.jar tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle decided not to use node word in this project name because of legal reasons. Current name of this thing is Project Avatar. Most like [Avatar.js](https://avatar-js.java.net/) is exactly that you're looking for.
You can find more details here https://avatar.java.net/

Cheers,
Vik

Update: here is another similar [SO question with detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289753/avatar-js-and-project-avatar)

Comment: Thx u for making it clear. Also can u please check my other unanswered quedtion about building avatar.js